# Crypto getRandomValue in Firefox add-on content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to use crypto.getRandomValue ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.crypto.getRandomValues)) in my Firefox add-on. But, I didn't find a way to have an access to crypto in my content script. Is there a way to do it?

**update**

I was mistaken, I've tried not in a content script, but directly in main.js. Do I need to use content script just for this function or it could be done without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me just fine... Maybe you misspelled `getRandomValues` as `getRandomValue` in your code as well.

#### Content scripts

```
var {PageMod} = require("sdk/page-mod");

// Content scripts should be able to use crypto just fine.
PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScript: 'console.log(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(10)));'
});
```

Logs some random data, as expected.

#### SDK modules, such as `main.js`

```
// SDK modules do not have a window, but we can always borrow the
// hidden window.

var {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var window = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;
console.log(window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(10)));
```

Logs some random data, as expected.

Comment: Note though about using `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow`. On add-on startup, you have to wait for `load` event to finish of `hiddenDOMWindow` otherwise you will get error when trying to access its propeties such as `.crypto`. On slow computers hiddenDOMWindow takes awhile to load, on fast computers it doesnt, so just check `if (hiddenDOMWindow && hiddenDOMWindow.crypto) { /*winodw loaded*/ } else { /* wait for iwndow to load so attach load event listner to hiddenDOMWindow */ }`

Comment: You are right, in this case it works, I've tried to have an access in main.js directly.

Comment: Direct usage of `hiddenDOMWindow` is not suggested, it's better use `sdk/addon/window` module for such purpose. Notice also that the main code of add-on will be executed only when such window reference is "ready", to avoid issues like the one described.

Comment: @ZER0 thank you, `sdk/addon/window` did the trick, I have a problem to pass the object in a module that have to use `crypto`. I use `openpgpjs` and I do `var openpgp = require("openpgp");`, apparently, `openpgp` doesn't see the `crypto`. Maybe, you know have to make a cheat here?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox are you using? Running this code in Firefox 31 in a content script seems to work fine for me:

```
var arr = new Uint16Array(6);
console.log(window.crypto.getRandomValues(arr));
```